Assert.IsEmpty deprecated
Just trying to run some old tests and it seems Assert.IsEmpty has been deprecated with the following error

CS0117 'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'IsEmpty'

I've tried googling but its not giving me anything useful.
Could anyone help me convert the following old code please
Testcase.axeResult = new AxeBuilder(Testcase.driver).Analyze();
Assert.IsEmpty(Testcase.axeResult.Violations);

Thanks in advance

you can check the count of violations directly and assert that it's zero.
Testcase.axeResult = new AxeBuilder(Testcase.driver).Analyze(); 
Assert.AreEqual(0, Testcase.axeResult.Violations.Count, "No violations should be found.");

Assert.AreEqual is used to verify that the count of violations is zero. If it's not zero, the test will fail, and the message "No violations should be found." will be displayed.

But you can also write is using Assert.That( Testcase.axeResult.Violations, Has.Count.EqualTo(0))

You haven't stated the version of NUnit you are using [always give versions!] but it appears you're on version 4, which eliminated "classic" asserts.
@Timir's answer and @icepickle's comment both work, but for completeness, here are some other options...

Stop using NUnit v4 and go back to v3... end of story.

Add using NUnit.Framework.Legacy and change your Assert.IsEmpty to ClassicAssert.IsEmpty.

Assert.That(TestCase.axeResult.Violations, Is.Empty);


The NUnit project has documented this change here.

For collections there's the class CollectionAssert:
CollectionAssert.IsEmpty(whatever);

